# Can I perform 1D integration by substitution in multiple integrals?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, coordinate-systems

Suppose I have an integral of the form:

$$\idotsint_D f({\bf{x}})dA = \int_{a_n}^{b_n}\ldots\int_{a_1}^{b_1}f({\bf{x}})dx_1\ldots dx_n$$

Can I perform a single variable calculus style integration by substition? If I fix all other variables in $f({\bf{x}})$ and consider $g(x_1) = f(x_1, c_2 \ldots, c_n)$, then I can make the substitution $u = h(x_1)$ and write $dx = \frac{1}{h'(x_1)}du$ to conclude:

$$\int_{a_1}^{b_1}g(x_1)dx_1 = \int_{h(a_1)}^{h(b_1)}\hat{g}(u)du$$

Assuming the substitution is well chosen s.t. $g(x_1, u)\frac{1}{h'(x_1)} = \hat{g}(u)$ and the problem is more tractable.

But if I try to carry this logic over to an iterated integral then I am transforming several variables, even if they are constant in this integral. Can I naively put these in the limits? I am not sure if I should start drawing pictures in the new system of coordinates to determine the limits I defined and if I should calculate Jacobians, or if I should just apply the formula from the 1 variable case.

If it helps, the integral that confused me was:

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{2}\frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{(x^2+y^2)^3}dydx$$

With the substition $u = x^2 + y^2$. I'm not sure how I would even calculate a Jacobian for this, without trying to horribly force square roots to write $x$ as a $x(u)$?, for that I need enough relations for a $2\times2$ matrix of partial derivatives, this is just one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a single variable substitution just like you did in single variable calculus.

you can say

$x = y\tan t$ and $dx = y\sec^2 t \ dt$

And it might help if you think of it as a two variable substitution, e.g.

$x = s\tan t\\
y = s$

and calculate the Jacobian.

$\left|\det\begin {bmatrix} \frac {\partial x}{\partial s} & \frac {\partial x}{\partial t}\\\frac {\partial y}{\partial s}&\frac {\partial y}{\partial t}\end{bmatrix}\right| = \left|\begin {bmatrix} \tan t & s\sec^2 t\\1&0\end{bmatrix}\right| = s \sec^2 t\ dt$

But what you are suggesting:

$u = x^2 + y^2$

looks like you are really reaching for a full change to polar coordinates.

$x = r\cos \theta\\y = r\sin\theta\\r^2 = x^2 + y^2\\ dx\ dy = r\ dr\ d\theta$

Comment: Makes a lot of sense. So the when I say $x = x(t)$ in the 2-d case its really $x = x(t,s)$, $y = y(t,s)$ where $y = s$? So the partial derivatives become $\frac{\partial x}{\partial t}$, $\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}$, $1$ and $0$ so the Jacobian determinant reduces to what you expect in 1 variable? The limits are as expected?